# Run Access queries with VBA from c#

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access

I would like to write a c# application that will read a huge number of Access queries from a table.  The table will have all the SQL statements of the queries.
The queries might contain Access functions and methods like InStr, DateAdd, etc.
It is not really feasible to rewrite all these statements in T-SQL, as the table will continually have new queries added to it.

So in short, is it possible to run Access SELECT queries (containing VBA functions) from c#, and read the results into a DataTable?

Comment: You would have to automate Access to run the queries, then find a way to read the data from Access, maybe via a temporary results table.

Comment: Reference the Microsoft Access interop assemblies from your C# project, you'll have pretty much the same object model VBA code plays with. Key point being, it's Access running the queries, not your C# code; the VBA stuff is embedded with the Access database, so C# doesn't even need to care about it.

Comment: The older "Jet" `(*.mdb)` version of the the Access ODBC driver was quite restricted in the number of built-in "Access functions" it supported. The newer "ACE" `(*.mdb, *.accdb)` ODBC driver supports a much wider range of those functions, including `DateAdd`, `Replace`, etc.. Have you tried running some of the more challenging queries from C# using `System.Data.Odbc` to see if they will actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an odd request, but I'm sure it's technically feasible to do this kind of thing.

```
string strProvider = "@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database3.accdb";
string strSql = "Select * from score";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
con.Open();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable scores = new DataTable();
da.Fill(scores);
dataGridView1.DataSource = scores;
```

And, with exception handling . . .

```
try
        {

        Dataset myDataSet=new Dataset();

        string connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\Database3.accdb";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from score", conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd );

        connection .Open();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet,"TableName");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.\n{0}", ex.Message);
              return;
        }
        finally
        {
              connection .Close();
        }
```

Comment: @ryguy2's answer does work. One problem I still sit with is custom VBA functions. Do you know if it's possible to add my custom VBA function in these queries? With code above I get "Undefined function 'MyFunction' in expression."